# Moving any RelativeLayout with finger (without changing layout params)

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a view, and I want to move it with finger. I wanted to get the xDelta and yDelta and just translate the matrix of the view (not image view, any view, RelativeLayout for example).
I am wondering how to do that:

1. Overriding RelativeLayout's onDraw and apply translation matrix there. Is that possible?
2. I am currently doing it with applying animation on each onTouch event. The animation is with duration 0 and the start/end of x/y is the same (setFillAfter = true). It just puts the view where I want. But isn't that too expensive?

Can't I manipulate the matrix of any view directly through onDraw? I tried something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (getDx() != 0 && getDy() != 0) {
        m = canvas.getMatrix();
        m.postTranslate(dx, dy);
        canvas.setMatrix(m);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

But it seems that I am doing it wrong.

Comment: I would rather draw View once on a Bitmap and translate the Bitmap. It would be more efficient, I think. When dragging the real view could be INVISIBLE or GONE.

Comment: So you think there is no way to manipulate the matrix directly?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to implement drag gesture then you can use **onTouchListener** and in its **MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE** set padding using setPadding to that view.

Here is the sample code:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    yourView.setPadding((int)event.getRawX(), (int)event.getRawY(), 0, 0);
```

Sample for onTouchListener :-

```
OnTouchListener drag= new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            break;
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

            break;
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
               img.setPadding((int)event.getRawX(), (int)event.getRawY(), 0, 0);
            break;
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

            break;
           }        return true;
    }
};
```

You need to create the dragging image at run time and have to adjust its position. In this sample code I have not adjusted the position so  the dragged image is not created at the position of touch. You also need to consider the height and width of the image to be dragged.

Hope it helps !

Comment: i am not sure how View will move using padding ? have you tried this

Comment: Yeah. I used is for implementing drag n drop feature for API level lower than 11.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to be the one to tell you that your problem is even easier than you thought, but here's what it looks like:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (getDx() != 0 && getDy() != 0) {
        canvas.translate(getDx(), getDy());
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Move your layout permanently (In case of temporary, we can use animation ) then Use [Drag And Drop API from android Official Page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) . Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things that would help in achieving it:

1. Make sure that your view originally has enough space in the direction you want to use. Like 'match_parent' etc
2. Use GestureDetector.onSimpleGestureListener and override **onDraw ( return true;) , onScroll** -- connect it using **onTouchEvent** and you will directly get the **distance** , or you can calculate yourself by using the **event1 and event2**
3. Store this information in variable(s) and call **invalidate()**
4. in your onDraw method - use this information by **canvas.translate(..use those variables..); super.onDraw(canvas);**

and your will achieve the result

PS: The drawing starts by taking left-top as 0,0